# How to Edit a row in the datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have created a data table. It has 3 column **Product_id**, **Product_name** and **Product_price**

```
    Datatable table= new DataTable("Product");

    table.Columns.Add("Product_id", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Product_name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Product_price", typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add(1, "abc", "100");
    table.Rows.Add(2, "xyz", "200");
```

Now I want to find by index, and update that row.

say for e.g.

I want to change value of **Product_name** column to "cde" that has the **Product_id** column value : 2.

Comment: please edit your question to include the code of what you've attempted so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

First you need to find a row with id == 2 then change the name so:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows) // search whole table
{
    if(dr["Product_id"] == 2) // if id==2
    {
        dr["Product_name"] = "cde"; //change the name
        //break; break or not depending on you
    }
}
```

You could also try these solutions:

```
table.Rows[1]["Product_name"] = "cde" // not recommended as it selects 2nd row as I know that it has id 2
```

Or:

```
DataRow dr = table.Select("Product_id=2").FirstOrDefault(); // finds all rows with id==2 and selects first or null if haven't found any
if(dr != null)
{
    dr["Product_name"] = "cde"; //changes the Product_name
}
```

Comment: I like the 'Select on DataTable' approach since looping thru a couple thousand rows will be slower.  I also studied the 'FirstOrDefault()' method.  If you are poling the ID field you are most likely looking for a single row.  Is adding the 'FirstOrDefault()' method faster than just Selecting without it?

Comment: Just thought I would mention that the square brackets are missing from the 'Select' on the table example.  It should read `DataRow[] dr =`

Comment: @DaveHampel FirstOrDefault() should return either null or single row, hence DataRow. DataRow[] would mean we expect an array of DataRow objects. On the other hand if you removed FirstOrDefault() (as you suggest in the first comment), then DataRow[] would be necessary as [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-8.0#system-data-datatable-select(system-string)) return type is DataRow[].

Answer (score 20):

You can find that row with

```
DataRow row = table.Select("Product_id=2").FirstOrDefault();
```

and update it

```
row["Product_name"] = "cde";
```

Comment: Although this works for OP question, please note, this solution only updates first record if select returns multiple records.

Comment: This solutions works great and as AaA says it only works for the first result, however if you are looking for a unique value on the datatable then this should work as expected

Answer (score 10):

Try the **SetField** method:

By passing column object :

```
table.Rows[rowIndex].SetField(column, value);
```

By Passing column index :

```
table.Rows[rowIndex].SetField(0 /*column index*/, value);
```

By Passing column name as string :

```
table.Rows[rowIndex].SetField("product_name" /*columnName*/, value);
```

Answer (score 8):

If your data set is too large first select required rows by Select(). it will stop further looping.

```
DataRow[] selected = table.Select("Product_id = 2")
```

Then loop through subset and update

```
    foreach (DataRow row in selected)
    {
        row["Product_price"] = "<new price>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse through the DataTable like below and set the value

```
foreach(DataTable thisTable in dataSet.Tables)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in thisTable.Rows)
    {
        row["Product_name"] = "cde";
    }
}
```

OR

```
thisTable.Rows[1]["Product_name"] = "cde";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's true, we can add a condition to validate the data and only then update... the 2nd method does that for the specific row though

Answer (score 2):

Try this I am also not 100 % sure

```
        for( int i = 0 ;i< dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           If(dt.Rows[i].Product_id == 2)
           {
              dt.Rows[i].Columns["Product_name"].ColumnName = "cde";
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
foreach(DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
{
rw["Obj_Amt"] = h.Decrypt(rw["Obj_Amt"].ToString());
dt.AcceptChanges();
rw.SetModified();
}
```

use SetModified() method to update data table value.