# Update Jquery Datatable Cell Value

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a jquery datatable with a many spans in it. The table is loaded in with ajax data from a DB then the spans are dynamically updated to match all the other spans with the same class when a user changed a value.

The issue I am having though is that when I update the spans datatable doesn't seem to know it was updated.

For example if I make update the value to `555` and then search for `555` it doesn't return a result.

I tried to use `.draw()` but it doesn't seem to work. How do I have datatable update all the cell values without destroying and rebuilding the table. Destroy just seems like massive overkill.

Comment: Are you updating the client-side table AND the db? Is the search performed on the server-side?

Comment: Everything is client side. The initial load gets ALL values to start and that is the only ajax call. The DataTable essentially acts like a normal  one after that without anymore ajax calls. Everything else is client side. If you look at may comment to Michael Emerson this fiddle jsfiddle.net/jebwq9yL illustrates the issue.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with client-side datatables, but it seems to me like you're updating the HTML, but not the underlying datatable. Maybe something like this would help:[stackoverflow.com/questions/19629644/how-to-edit-a-row-in-the-datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629644/how-to-edit-a-row-in-the-datatable)

Comment: I also think that is the issue. I can't seem to find a way to tell the datatable that I have changed the html value of a cell. I looked that the link you gave and the issue I have is that it talks about doing it by column name and I need to do it by span class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been beating on this for a while now and I think it may have to do with cache that datatable uses. What I found though was that if you find the cell then set the data attribute to the html value of the cell it works. So for example you would do something like this.

```
var UpdateTD = $(".changemade").parent('td');
table.cell( UpdateTD ).data( UpdateTD.html()).draw();
```

That is the only way I have found to make to make it work. It doesn't seem like the best way to do this, but it does work. Here is the updated fiddle showing it in action https://jsfiddle.net/jebwq9yL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Define the `table` as global variable like this

HTML Update 
Used `<td class="changemade">Tiger Nixon</td>`. removed span from your code. to access a cell you have to give class name or id to the td not span.

```js
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
  ........
  // DataTable
  table = $('#example').DataTable();
  ........
  });
$('.changebutton').on('click', function () {
    // update cell value based on selector
    table.cell($('.changemade')).data('MEOW!').draw()
});
});
//and use this code to listen the draw event.
table.on('draw', function() {
  alert('table has been re-drawn')
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/58rycL0g/1/)

In your fiddle the search works because  variable `table` and `search function` are in same scope but `table.draw` is out of the scope so it is not working

Comment: Even if you do that though you still can't search for the new value. If you search for "MEOW!" it still returns no results. I clicked the button saw the nixon value change to "MEOW!", but then when I search for it in the global search or the name search it will not return results.

Comment: Interesting I wonder why it doesn't work with the span, but it does without it. In case I have to use the span though because I have other hidden elements in there too like a loading progress bar.

Comment: you answer is correct. Datatables need a selector to update the value so i removed span. if you get the selector using `parent` that is ok, what if you have n number of elements where you cannot  write code for finding each span parent ?

Comment: What I did in my production code was that each time I updated the span I did this ThisSpan.closest('table').DataTable().cell( ThisSpan.parent('td') ).data( ThisSpan.parent('td').html() ).draw(); so essentially what I was doing was telling datatable to make the html in the cell the data value for that cell

Comment: like what ? I didn't get you

Comment: All you need is to be able to select the span. Then you go back up the dom to the TD. You then use that to select the cell and set the data value of the cell to the html value of that td. So you are telling datatable that the data value is the html value you just set. If you have multiple tables like I do you can even go up the dom from the span to the datatable itself.