# To assign datarow with new value in C#

Tags: c#

iam looking into datatable and fetching line by line,

iam having 50 length values. i want to assign 10th length value as "text".

but it is not stored in datarow after assigned

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtSource.Rows)
{
    if (row.ItemArray[17].ToString().Length > 32)
     {
         string ss=   "text";  
         row.ItemArray[17] = ss; // here it is not added in itemarray
     }
}
```

Comment: Do not use ItemArray to store your value. Just _row[17]_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Edit a row in the datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629644/how-to-edit-a-row-in-the-datatable)

Comment: Btw, what means _" i want to assign 10th length value as "text""_?

Answer (score 10):

[`DataRow.ItemArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a new array on the fly that contains all fields. So when you modify this array you won't modify the `DataRow` itself.  You should use the `DataRow` indexer:

```
row[17] = ss;
```

You can use `ItemArray` when you need all objects in an array or when you want to assign the whole row's fields at once by assigning an array to this property.