# How to update DataGridView cell in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in c# WinForms

In this form I fill a big DataGridView with data, the process behind takes long time.

anyway, my issue is that I want to update one cell in that DataGridView based on criteria

DataGridView has 4 columns, StNo, StName, StAge, StMark.

I want to search for StNo = 123 and update their StMark to be 68

I tried the following but does not work

```
grd1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => x.Cells["StNo"].Value.ToString() == "123")["StMark"] = 68;
```

How to do that?

Comment: First, use a `DataTable` and set it as your DataSource, don't directly access the `DataGridView`. Then, see here: [How to Edit a row in the datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19629644)

Comment: Is there a way to update the datagridview?

Comment: If you set a DataTable as your DataSource and update it, your DataGridView will automatically update.

Comment: You should follow @Fabio ‘s answer. You will need to break the current (invalid) one line of code into two (2) steps. You need to make sure that when the query returns the results from `Where(x => x.Cells["StNo"].Value.ToString() == "123"` … that "something" is actually returned. Using your approach assumes that "something" is always returned. The code MUST check for the case when nothing is returned. Otherwise, a null exception is guaranteed. You can apply this same idea to the grid or the grids data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridView` is a winforms control which responsible for displaying given records in UI and provide user's input to the underlying records via different events.

So instead of updating values via `DataGridView` - update underlying records.

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get; set; }
}

public class MyForm
{
    public readonly BindingList<Student> _sutdents;

    public MyForm()
    {
        _students = new BindingList<Student>();
        myDataGridView.DataSource = _students;
    }

    private void AddStudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var student = new Student
        {
            Number = int.Parse(textboxNumber.Text),
            Name = textboxName.Text,
            Name = int.Parse(textboxAge.Text),
            Name = int.Parse(textboxMark.Text),
        };

        _students.Add(student);
    }
    // After button click you should see that new student appears in the DataGridView

    // Now you can update existing students from code without "touching" DataGridView
    private void UpdateMarkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var studentNumber = int.Parse(textboxNewMarkStudentNumber.Text);
        var newMark = int.Parse(textboxNewMark.Text);

        var student = _students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Number = studentNumber);
        if (student != null)
        {
            student.Mark = newMark;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your life, made easy:

- add a new DataSet file to your project, open it, name it StudentDataSet in the property grid
- right click, add a new DataTable to the surface, name it Students
- add columns of StNo (make it an int in the property grid), StName, StAge (int), StMark (int)
- right click StNo and make it a primary key
- save
- switch to the form designer, open the Data Sources panel (view menu.. other windows)
- drag the node representing the table, onto the form. A datagridview appears

Now the code you need for updating a Mark is:

```
var s = studentDataSet.Students.FindByStNo(123);
if(s!=null)
  s.StMark = 99;
```

Yes, that's all you need (plus you need to load the table with student data)

---

If these students come out of a database, you can make your life easier in the second step by not adding a DataTable but instead adding a TableAdapter and setting up the db connection/query that pulls them out of the db..